# Layout Preview toolbar doesn't show in android studio 3.6.1

Tags: android, layout

In my android studio there is no toolbar like in the photo. ( the red marked part ). My version is 3.6.1. 
I've tried to look in setting but didn't find anything.
Does anyone know how to enable this toolbar.

[This is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4oYE.jpg)
[this is what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnxZK.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is on the right upside corner of the xml, three icons where you can select if you want to see only the code, the code and the preview or only the design.

This link will help you: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases